# Bootstrap Flexbox horizontal scrolling element not workin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have written some CSS and used bootstrap to create a horizontal div with scroll ability but the output is not proper if I add
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

In My Code

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8381b.jpg)
My Code:

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1px;
  height: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555; 
}
.scrolling-wrapper{
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.card-block{
    height: 200px;
    width: 163px;
    background-color: #141414;
    border: none;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.card-block img{
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 82px;
    width: 82px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.card-block span{
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.card-block a{
    background-color: #007bdc;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
</style>
    <div class="scrolling-wrapper row flex-row flex-nowrap mt-6 pb-6 pt-3">
            
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="card card-block card-1">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                    <span>
                        Om Prakash
                    </span>
                    <a href="#">
                        More Info
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="card card-block card-2">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="card card-block card-3">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="card card-block card-4">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="card card-block card-5">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="card card-block card-6">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="card card-block card-7">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="card card-block card-8">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="card card-block card-9">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="card card-block card-10">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Everything seems to be running as described. Can you go into detail on what your issue is? The horizontal scroll seems to be functioning in snippet and fiddle.

Comment: I want the OutPut like this [link](https://server.itjmovies.com:2629/down/fd07n51VxLEF) but when I add the Meta viewport tag all the cards become overlayed. @Kameron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using col-auto instead of col-2 and mx-0 with row

```html
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <style>
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 1px;
      height: 0px;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: #f1f1f1; 
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: #888; 
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
      background: #555; 
    }
    .scrolling-wrapper{
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
    .card-block{
        height: 200px;
        width: 163px;
        background-color: #141414;
        border: none;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }
    .card-block img{
        display: block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 82px;
        width: 82px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .card-block span{
        display: block;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #fff;
        margin-top: 4px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    .card-block a{
        background-color: #007bdc;
        padding-left: 4px;
        padding-right: 4px;
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin-top: 12px;
    }
    </style>
        <div class="scrolling-wrapper row mx-0 flex-nowrap mt-6 pt-3">

  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="card card-block card-1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
      <span>
        Om Prakash
      </span>
      <a href="#">
        More Info
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="card card-block card-2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="card card-block card-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="card card-block card-4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="card card-block card-5">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="card card-block card-6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="card card-block card-7">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="card card-block card-8">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="card card-block card-9">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="card card-block card-10">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div> <p>Hello I'm a Text</p></div>
    
    <br/>
    <br/>
```

Comment: Umm, this worked but all other elements in body are also scrolling horizontally, can you please update your code, as like only this div will scroll horizontally and all other elements will remain as they were. Like in Instagram Mobile (User Suggestion).

Comment: if you put something outside of scrolling-wrapper then that element will not scroll, check updated answer

Comment: Please have a look at this [projectPage](https://www.miltehein.com/auth/login/) Use LoGin `admin@admin.com` and pass `123` and use the mobile version

Comment: All the elements are scrolling horizontally. I think so.. After logging in you can see the output

Comment: Sorry I miss spelled some div class now it's working perfectly...

Comment: yes I saw that, it's looking good now